# How can I pass an F# delegate to a P/Invoke method expecting a function pointer?

Tags: winapi, f#, delegates, pinvoke

I'm attempting to set up a low-level keyboard hook using P/Invoke in an F# application.  The Win32 function `SetWindowsHookEx` takes a `HOOKPROC` for its second argument, which I've represented as a delegate of `(int * IntPtr * IntPtr) -> IntPtr`, similar to how this would be handled in C#.  When calling the method, I get a `MarshalDirectiveException` stating that the delegate parameter cannot be marshaled because

> Generic types cannot be marshaled

I'm not sure how generics are involved, as all types are concretely specified.  Can anyone shed some light on this?  Code follows.

**EDIT**

This may have to do with the way the F# compiler deals with type signatures - Reflector indicates that the delegate `LowLevelKeyboardProc` is implemented as a method which accepts one argument of type `Tuple<int, IntPtr, IntPtr>` - and there would be the un-marshalable generic type.  Is there a way around this somehow, or are F# functions simply not capable of being marshaled to native function pointers?

```
let WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13

type LowLevelKeyboardProc = delegate of (int * IntPtr * IntPtr) -> IntPtr

[<DllImport("user32.dll")>]
extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idhook, LowLevelKeyboardProc proc, IntPtr hMod, UInt32 threadId)

[<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>]
extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName)

let SetHook (proc: LowLevelKeyboardProc) =
    use curProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess ()
    use curMod = curProc.MainModule

    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curMod.ModuleName), 0u)
```

Comment: +1 for trying to p/invoke from F# and *passing a delegate*. I honestly don't know if that can even be done.

Comment: I think the result type should simply be `int`, not `IntPtr`. But I guess that will not make a difference with the error message...; suggestion: add the code that calls `SetHook`, maybe there is a problem there?

Comment: @wmeyer : A return type of `int` rather than `nativeint` would fail on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi : This is standard for passing callbacks to native code in all .NET languages; nothing special about using F# for this.

Comment: @ildjarn, I was wary of F# functions used as delegates for some reason, but your mentioning of curried and tupled forms clarified that. Thanks :)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi : I'll admit, it's not obvious at first. `delegate of (int * int) -> int` defines a unary delegate taking an actual `Tuple<int, int>` whereas `delegate of int * int -> int` defines a binary function taking two `int`s. But, the latter must be used with a curried function even though it *appears* to use tuple syntax. Anyway, the non-obvious semantics of the former version is what was causing Ben's error, as `Tuple<int, nativeint, nativeint>` is quite clearly a generic.

Comment: @ildjam Non-obvious semantics indeed!  Thanks for clearing this up; the apparent inability to create a "proper" delegate in F# was really bothering me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `LowLevelKeyboardProc` definition is wrong. Change from

```
type LowLevelKeyboardProc = delegate of (int * IntPtr * IntPtr) -> IntPtr
```

to

```
type LowLevelKeyboardProc = delegate of int * IntPtr * IntPtr -> IntPtr
```

or better yet

```
type LowLevelKeyboardProc = delegate of int * nativeint * nativeint -> nativeint
```

or better yet

```
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT =
    val vkCode      : uint32
    val scanCode    : uint32
    val flags       : uint32
    val time        : uint32
    val dwExtraInfo : nativeint

type LowLevelKeyboardProc =
    delegate of int * nativeint * KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT -> nativeint
```

In all of the above cases, `proc` will need to use curried form rather than tupled form.

Also note that you should add `SetLastError = true` to all of the `extern`ed functions whose documentation says to call `GetLastError` upon failure (which is the case for `GetModuleHandle`, `SetWindowsHookEx`, and `UnhookWindowsHookEx`). That way if any fail (and you should be checking the return values...), you can simply raise a `Win32Exception` or call [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) to get proper diagnostics.

**EDIT**: Just for the sake of clarity, here are all the P/Invoke signatures I successfully tested locally:

```
[<Literal>]
let WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13

[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT =
    val vkCode      : uint32
    val scanCode    : uint32
    val flags       : uint32
    val time        : uint32
    val dwExtraInfo : nativeint

type LowLevelKeyboardProc = delegate of int * nativeint * KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT -> nativeint

[<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>]
extern uint32 GetCurrentThreadId()

[<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)>]
extern nativeint GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName)

[<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)>]
extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(nativeint hhk)

[<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)>]
extern nativeint SetWindowsHookEx(int idhook, LowLevelKeyboardProc proc, nativeint hMod, uint32 threadId)
```

Also note that this would work equally as well, if you prefer value semantics for `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`:

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT =
    val vkCode      : uint32
    val scanCode    : uint32
    val flags       : uint32
    val time        : uint32
    val dwExtraInfo : nativeint

type LowLevelKeyboardProc = delegate of int * nativeint * byref<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT> -> nativeint
```

Comment: how do you usually test your P/Invokes?

Comment: @GregC : Depends on the level of complexity. In this case, I wrote a small C++ console app to determine expected behavior then verified that the F# app had the same. In more complex cases I usually write a C++ .dll that exports functions with the same signatures of those I ultimately wish to call, and have those functions just blindly forward data back and forth to the underlying WinAPI functions, logging as it does so. Then I can look over the logging output to make sure the marshaling behavior is sane.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use managed C++ with this.  It can make a lot of the translation pretty seamless.  You won't need P/Invoke then.

EDIT:  I'd like to note one fairly important thing: compiler will do more type-checking for you.  I am sure you love your type-checking, since you use F# for the rest of the app (hopefully).